# transform List using lambda expressions

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, lambda

I have created a function to transform the elements of a list:

```
private List<Hostel> build(List<Hotel> hotels) {
         return hotels.stream().map(h -> convert(h)).collect(toList());
    }
```

but I have a compilation error:

```
required type: List<Hostel>
Provided: List<List<Hostel>>
```

Comment: What is the return-type of `convert()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error it seems `convert(h)` return a `List<Hostel>`, for that when you use a map, and collect the result is `List<List<Hostel>>`, to get `List<Hostel>`, you have to use `flatMap` instead of map, like this:

```
.flatMap(h -> convert(h).stream())
```